# How can I configure the Bluemix Pipeline to either tag builds or create a work item (defect) according to the state of the build?

Tags: continuous-integration, agile, ibm-cloud, devops

I have a Build & Deploy Pipeline in Bluemix, I would like to create a condition where, if the build fails, it will automatically assign a defect (i.e., work item in the "Track & Plan" page) to whoever delivered the very latest change (or just assign to the main owner of the App/Project), also, if the build is completed successfully, I would like to tag it.

Tagging is ok, that's general GIT knowledge, I just wanted to solve 2 Problems with that plan:

1. How do we trigger a specific subsequent Stage in the pipeline if the current build fails/passes?
2. How do I create a work item from the pipeline? Do I need to create a separate GIT repo and build some sort of API package that allows me to invoke a mechanism that creates the ticket?

I guess I'm going too maverick with this Pipeline, please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now you can not create a work item from the pipeline.  That is a great feature improvement and I can take it back to the team.

For your question about triggering a stage if something passes or fails...  The way it works now only the next stage will be triggered if the previous is successful.  The pipeline is based on Jenkins and Jenkins doesn't allow you to trigger a specific job if a job passes or fails.  You would want to detect the pass or fail in your stage and do your logic based on that.

Comment: Hey, but Jenkins can achieve that through plugins :) https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: As of right now we dont have a have to add plugins to your stages right now.  I can take this feedback to the team though.